# Show address details for clicked row in table using Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html-table, alpine.js, laravel-10

In table, I have a "View Address" button where when I click, it will show the address details. It works fine but however, since I am still new in Alpine.js, when I click the view address it shows all address details for all rows in the table. Below is my code:

```html
<tbody class="overflow-y-auto" x-data="{ show: false }">
    @foreach ($customer as $customers)
        <tr class="border-b border-gray-200">
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900"></td>
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900">{{ $customers->id }}</td>
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900">{{ $customers->name }}</td>
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900">{{ $customers->email }}</td>
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900">
                <div>
                    <button class="address-button" x-on:click=" show=!show ">View Address</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900">
                <a href="{{ route('customers.edit', $customers->id) }}"
                    class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000"
                        stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                        <path d="M20 14.66V20a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h5.34"></path>
                        <polygon points="18 2 22 6 12 16 8 16 8 12 18 2"></polygon>
                    </svg></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr x-show="show" class="border-b border-gray-200">
            <td class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900"></td>
            <td colspan="5" class="px-2 py-1 whitespace-nowrap text-xs text-gray-900">
                @if ($customers->addresses)
                    @php
                        $addresses = is_string($customers->addresses) ? json_decode($customers->addresses, true) : $customers->addresses;
                        $addresses = isset($addresses['addresses']) ? $addresses['addresses'] : $addresses;
                        $num = 1;
                    @endphp
                    @if (!empty($addresses) && is_array($addresses))
                        @foreach ($addresses as $address)
                            <div class="">
                                <strong>Address {{ $num }}</strong><br>

                                @if (array_key_exists('street1', $address))
                                    <strong>Street 1:</strong> {{ $address['street1'] }}<br>
                                @endif
                                @if (array_key_exists('street2', $address))
                                    <strong>Street 2:</strong> {{ $address['street2'] }}<br>
                                @endif
                                @if (array_key_exists('postcode', $address))
                                    <strong>Postcode:</strong> {{ $address['postcode'] }}<br>
                                @endif
                                @if (array_key_exists('city', $address))
                                    <strong>City:</strong> {{ $address['city'] }}<br>
                                @endif
                                @if (array_key_exists('state', $address))
                                    <strong>State:</strong> {{ $address['state'] }}<br>
                                @endif
                                @if (array_key_exists('country', $address))
                                    <strong>Country:</strong> {{ $address['country'] }}<br>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            @if (!$loop->last)
                                <br>
                            @endif
                            @php
                                $num++;
                            @endphp
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I believe that since I declare `<tr x-show="show">`, it will show all the address details for all rows. I tried to use based on `$customer->id` but somehow it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set only one variable *show* to handle all the rows, so when its value changes all the rows are displayed accordingly

To fix this without upsetting everything, we can turn the *show* variable into an array and use the @foreach loop index to access to it, so that each address section has its own *show[n]* variable (I use a custom variable instead of *$loop->index* as it is more concise):

```blade
<tbody class="overflow-y-auto" x-data="{ show: Array.from({length: {{ count($customer) }} }, () => false) }">

        @foreach ($customer as $rowN => $customers)

            <tr>

            .....

               <button class="address-button" x-on:click="show[{{$rowN}}] = !show[{{$rowN}}]">View Address</button>

            .....

            </tr>
 
            <tr x-show="show[{{$rowN}}]" class="border-b border-gray-200">

                .....

                @if ($customers->addresses)
                    .....
                @endif

                .....
  
            </tr>
```

Also to avoid the flickering of the hidden rows when the page is rendered, you can add a *x-cloak* to the address rows:

```blade
<tr x-cloak x-show="show[{{$rowN}}]" class="border-b border-gray-200">
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works!! I didnt know it can use array that way. Thank you very much very cool. and the extra info on x-cloak also is very helpful.